# there was internal issue with the rendering process - XAML previewer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am totaly new to xamarin framework, i have just created an app with UI technology Xamarin.Forms and Code Sharing Strategy .NET Standard and i am using Visual Studio 2017 15.5.7 .

When I try to preview the default app template with the XAML Previewer, I get this error "There was an internal issue with the rendering process". I have given the screenshot below. I have tried alot to solve the problem but faild.
What should i do to solve this problem?

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmfedwXYYdKe3HfQbHZBsM31ZSTO

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/#Xamarin_Forms_Previewer) and [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/).

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Had to downgrade. Note for non-Mac users: if you don't have a Mac, the previewer won't work, even for Android. All you'll get is a blue/gray screen. This bug needs to be fixed by Xamarin.

**On your Mac:**

- Switch back to the stable channel on Xamarin Studio if you're not on
  it already.
- Install Xcode 8.2.

**On Windows:**
Well, I had to uninstall VS 2017, install VS 2015, download the manual installer (the universal installer didn't work) from

- https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads ->
- Show All Versions ->
- Xamarin.Android ->
- Download latest version (you only need to download Android --
  Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android point to the same "manual" installer
  on Windows)
- , install it, configure the Mac agent. This finally let the previewer
  work... for iOS.

Android preview still doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

Solved it. You need to update to JDK 8 and set it to use that directory in

- Tools ->
- Options ->
- Xamarin ->
- Android.

  Then, make sure you uninstall any 32 bit version of the JDK or all you'll get is `XFPageRendererView` instead of your `XAML`. TOOK FOREVER TO FIGURE OUT. This is how I spend my Christmas

Now, the only annoying thing is intellisense doesn't work on my XAML files. SIGH, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

You have to right-click on the XAML file and Open With... -> XAML Designer. The designer with encoding option didn't work for me, but the regular designer did. How odd.